# MS Access Update Query Truncates Text

Tags: ms-access

I'm running an update query that involves Long Text (Memo) fields from a table:

```
UPDATE Core, Interpretation SET Core.SEIS_SS_Final = 434, 
Core.SEIS_SS_Final_SH = [Interpretation].[Short_Hand], 
Core.SEIS_SS_Final_Std = [Interpretation].[Student_Txt], 
Core.SEIS_SS_Final_Adv = [Interpretation].[Advisor_Txt] WHERE 
(Core.SID =[Forms]![Process_frm]![SID]) AND 
(Interpretation.Interpretation_id=545);
```

The fields in the table Core are set to Long Text, but after the update, they are truncated to 256 characters (Short Text length).

I've checked the Interpretation table and the fields are okay in there (they are not truncated) so something is happening when I run the query.

The absolutely bizarre thing is that I've been running this query for six months and this is the first time it's happened. I ran it this morning and have the output, which is not truncated---but now suddenly it's truncating, and I can't think of what I could have done to make it break.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help

Comment: That's certainly strange, you can review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html for common reasons memo fields truncate, but at least in the SQL, I can see none of those reasons.

Comment: Thanks Erik---I did check out allen browne's scenarios but I don't see how any would apply to my issue. I've double checked that the long text fields are getting truncated at the Update (not before or after somehow).